# MySQL collation and PHP charset conflict

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, collation

I have a bunch of Danish text taken from a latin-1 MySQL database and it displays correctly when echoed in PHP. The problem starts when I need to echo some other Danish characters, which are not taken from the database.

What I do is actually output the header

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

to also let the non-queried characters to display correctly as well.

Problems is, when I do that the queried characters display incorrectly.

Comment: you should switch to utf-8 instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because the data is stored in a latin-1 collated table doesn't mean that it's latin-1 encoded. This is due to MySQL not doing any character translation when the connection `SET NAMES` setting is the same as the collation.

I suspect that you have some UTF8 characters stored in a latin1 database which is confusing the issue.

For more help please can you add details of the:

- MySQL connection encoding that you have set
- Details of where the "non-queried" characters are coming from

Comment: Don’t use `SET NAMES` but [`mysql_set_charset`](http://php.net/mysql_set_charset).

Comment: well, that will work if you're using the default MySQL adaptor. I included details of the different methods depending on adaptor in a blog post I wrote a couple of weeks ago: http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/how-to-avoid-character-encoding-problems-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

Use unicode. UTF-8 => the right way.

So, set utf8_unicode_ci in database, UTF-8 as page charset and before your query set mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");