# Charset problem upon publishing PHP + MySQL website

Tags: php, mysql, iis, character-encoding

I have published my website to a server but I'm tearing off my hair due to character problems. Locally it all works fine despite any dumbness of mine (unclear or mismatched charsets). Let's take just one table as example because it satisfies our conditions:

**My local scenario**

- PHP 5.3.0
- Apache 2.2.11
- MySQL 5.1.36-community-log

  - connection: utf8_general_ci
  - database: latin1_general_ci
  - table: latin1_general_ci
- google chrome browser v. 12.0.742.100 w/ charset ISO-8859-1
- php page charset set as: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />`
- local: notice the words "Matéria" - comes from html - and "Notícia" - comes from database - both display the accents correctly:

[image: expected behaviour locally]

**My host scenario**

- PHP 5.3.6
- IIS running FastCGI
- MYSQL 5.5.13

  - connection: utf8_general_ci
  - database: latin1_general_ci
  - table: latin1_general_ci
- google chrome browser v. 12.0.742.100 w/ charset ISO-8859-1
- php page charset set as: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />`
- host: notice how "Notícia" has trouble showing itself:

[image: wrong behaviour on host]

I've read a few stuff, including this [very good article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) stablishing a common ground for developers.

**I have considered**:

- the problem being the actual data in the tables (despite it having a latin1_general_ci collation maybe the data is actually stored differently as [this mate states it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935117/mysql-collation-and-php-charset-conflict));
- the problem having some ackward relation to IIS (when one runs PHP under IIS one has a tendency to blame IIS often);
- my innacurate programming skills playing tricks on me once again

anyone offering some help? I can offer some brazilian portuguese lessons, some advice on spiritual life or just a little chat about anything, but I must solve this problem and *you* may be able to help me.

thanks in advance,

Comment: The data is coming from MySQL? How did you go about transferring the database?

Comment: only the buttons "A Gazeta", "A tribuna" and "Notícia Agora" are comming from mySQL. for the transfer I have exported the table structure and data, copied the SQL statements and executed them in the host database, all using phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using anything but UTF8 for your collation/encoding. Set utf8_general_ci to your db and make sure all tables/columns have the same collation. Use UTF8 in your html head tag. You have listed yourself that your connection, html and db have different encoding. It seems to work on your machine, but there's no guarantee it'll fly anywhere else.

Comment: I could do that but why not get the grips on why it works locally and not online? changing to utf-8 is not our best option as it would imply in changing lots of code and the database itself, so any other thoughts? but thanks anyway for the suggestion, I'll surely be reading more on charsets to understand why I should head for UTF-8 right now.

Comment: I forgot to add that **INSERTing** (from a php page) an item which contains accented chars throws an error and does not complete the operation.

Comment: I suspect that the initial issue was a result of how the data was transferred. Now as for inserting, you would have to provide code as to how you are inserting the data and what kind of error you get.

Comment: You have mentioned MySQL collations, but what are the charsets?

Comment: Can you set a latin1 collation without a latin1 charset?

Comment: Yes if charsets are compatible. For example if database is in utf8 then you can set latin1 collation.

Comment: Other possible problem is charset in HTTP headers. If charset is set in HTTP headers this takes precedence over HTML meta content-type.

Comment: Have you tried using `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`? That's what I always use...

Comment: Hi all... Turns out the database data was stored as UTF-8 so I had to go through each .php file and change its Encoding (using the meta tag) to UTF-8 AND resave the files as UTF-8 (with BOM, which makes technically no difference for UTF-8 except stating it as UTF-8). We'd rather change the php files than changing the database data itself which would be a pain (and probably wrong). cheers you all. the best community for programming help everytime. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ISO-charsets then you have to make sure that your text is stored with the same charset as it is going to be displayed.

That is where your problem is located.

The question is as what charset has your í been saved? This is **not** influenced by your DB-settings. As opposed to common opinion, your DB only uses charsets for collating purposes. But it just saves the bit-sequence as is.

Load the site into a browser and then force the browser to use ISO-1 and see if it is displayed correctly. If yes, it's stored as ISO-1 and if not something else.

Thing is:

- With a properly placed  <meta http-equiv="Co... at the beginning of the code you can almost always make a browser use this charset.
- But if not then your it's a bit undefined what will happen. Some browsers use heuristics to guess the charset.

Comment: Raffael... Turns out the database data was stored as UTF-8 so I had to go through each .php file and chande its Encoding to UTF-8 AND resave the files as UTF-8 (with BOM, which makes technically no difference for UTF-8 except stating it as UTF-8). We'd rather change the php files than changing the database data itself which would be a pain (and probably **wrong**). cheers.

Comment: and anyway, go UTF8 all the way and you won't have any problems ... not even with PHP5.2

Answer (score 0):

I ugraded mysql on my local fedora linux machine from 5.1 to 5.5 and had problems with my charset.  I found that the upgrade was not complete just by installing the software.  I had to follow the [instructions from the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html) after the upgrade to fix a number of problems.  That document has a number of steps that could well fix the issue.  While you shouldn't skip directly to it - running mysql_upgrade was a big help.